# How to split set on equidistant subsets with maximum mean subset size?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, computer-science, graph-theory

I have a set of N objects and N * N distances between them. I want to cluster this set on subsets, such that in each cluster there are all objects has the same distance and mean(cluster_size) on all clusters is maximized.

I tried to solve this task by such algorithm:

1. Lets enumerate all unique distances between objects.
2. For each unique distance X lets build graph based with objects as nodes and adjacency matrix, where edge between A and B is present if distance between objects A and B is exactly X
3. Lets find maximum clique in this graph. If size of this clique is bigger than current maximum - update maximum and store clique as Result
4. Delete objects stored in Result from set of objects
5. Repeat until set of objects is not empty

Is there are any more efficient [approximate] solution?

Answer (score 1):

Mean(cluster size) = total number of points / number of clusters

The only way to maximize this is to minimize the number of clusters. That seems a fairly bad choice as optimization target. You may want to reconsider this objective.

Apart from that I think your algorithm is fairly sensible. As the problem likely is NP hard, you do want to use a greedy approximation.

I suggest to be more lazy in recomputing, and add some bounds.

1. Build subgraphs for every unique distance.
2. Sort subgraphs by size, descending.
3. Unless you have a cached value from a previous iteration, find the largest clique in each subgraph. Remember the overall largest clique. Stop if the current largest is larger than the remaining subgraphs.
4. Output best subgraph found.
5. Remove the contained nodes from all graphs, and forget those best cliques that contain any of the nodes just found. Go back to 2.